# What is the most appropriate wpf control for showing a set of words as a text?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I want to show a **large set of words** , **as a text** (not as a grid or list) that **each word has a set of additional properties** like word_id and word_type.

so what is the most appropriate WPF control for this?
Appropriate means having a **suitable performance**, **binding capabilities** and all things to deal with word and text.

- ListView
- FlowDocument
- DocumentView
- WebBrowser + javascript
- TextBlock + Run

or something else?

Comment: The answer depends greatly on the business requirements... Technical optimization could be applied, but the requirements can guide the optimization. Ex: should the display be paginated ? Does the presentation must be a grid, a tree ? How does the user have to navigate through the words ? etc.

Comment: @SteveB is correct, it depends greatly on what it actually needs to look like and what interactivity behaviour is required as well. It's easier to start with something close to the behaviour you want and retemplate it than to build a load of custom behaviour from scratch, although sometimes that path gets you better performance. You may also wish to consider ItemsControl, which is the base of controls like ListBox.

Comment: @ARZ 1. Are you planning to use different fonts for your words? 2. Is it not tags editor? 3. Are you forced to use WPF?

Comment: Presents sequence of words like a text. paginating is good but not essential. navigate using a mouseClick or keyPressing.

Comment: @Dmitry: 1.Not different fonts but different colors. 2.No. 3.Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use `WrapPanel` / a custom `VirtualizingWrapPanel` for displaying the items and `Converters` / `Triggers` / `VisualStateManager` for managing the look - subject to your functional reqs.

Here's my take on it:

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace GridA
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.Loaded += (o, e) => 
            {
                this.i.ItemsSource = "I am a penel which displays words as seperate items. Feel free to resize myself.".Split(" ".ToCharArray());
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Markup:

```
<Window x:Class="GridA.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid TextBlock.FontSize="20">
        <ItemsControl x:Name="i">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Label Margin="3" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="2" Content="{Binding}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea what [`Labels`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.label.aspx) are for? (Hint: Not this.)

Comment: @dowhilefor, maybe you're right. We tried both labels and textblocks in large datagrid - I can't say that it makes any difference performance wise. What it does make difference is that lebel supports for borders, you'll have to use borders with textblocks. Makes sense? And I agree, by no means the answer is wrong per se. So, there must be something else convincing your friend to minus it;) - since it's not the first occurance I put my educated guess in the comments.

Comment: +1 because I like this solution, although I would definitely use `TextBlocks` instead of `Labels`. They contain fewer elements, so performance is better.

Comment: @Rachel Like I said the reason for choosing Labels is you get 'free' borders with them:)

Comment: @Dmitry Last I checked (which was a few versions ago) Labels contained 13 elements while TextBlocks contained 2. That's a huge difference when you have a large number of elements on the screen. I don't think the difference is nearly so bad now, however I would still use TextBlocks (or TextBlocks w/ a Border around them) unless you need Label-Specific capabilities

Comment: @Rachel perhaps you're right. My answer wasn't really about label vs texblock comparison anyhow.

Comment: The performace is even less of an issue but this question is about displaying words, *as they are*, and Labels **don't do that**, they process underscores into access text in case you still did not get that, your answer hence is wrong to some degree *and* it performs badly.

Comment: @Dmitry How to get access to wrapPanel children (a specific Label or TextBlock) by Item Index? When I try to this I get exception :"Panel must be nested in ItemsControl to get and show items."

Comment: @ARZ what are you trying to do?

Comment: ((WrapPanel)i.ItemsPanel.LoadContent()).Children

Comment: @ARZ Sorry, could you give us a higher level description - as in - set border colors for the item controls or smth. like that. Normally, you don't need to have acccess to the physical controls representing your items, almost everything can be done by extending your item's template.

Comment: But if you still want it - you can give your panel a name, using x:Name="PanelName" attribute and then (only after your control gets loaded) use controlInstance.FindName("PanelName").

Comment: Forgot it! I save the current clicked TextBlock as a public control and do the job. thanks ;)